# spring amqp synchronous call using sendAndReceive example

Tags: spring-integration, synchronous, spring-amqp

I very new to java, and i have to implement a synchronous messaging i tried convertSendAndReceive and sendAndReceive with the spring-rabbit-helloworld example, but nothing worked.
please anyone help me out.
Any link to working example using sendAndReceive will be much appriciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/tree/master/helloworld is exactly what you need. If you are facing some issue with that it would be great when you share with us what's going on there: StackTrace in logs, some your home work with that code etc.

Comment: Unfortunately there is NO exactly sendAndReceive OR convertSendAndReceive example. There are just send and just receive. I can't find any working sendANDReceive example.